# Firebase app crashes with "unfortunately stopped"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried about 100 times to solve this problem but still the same error:

> unfortunately stopped

Here are my deps:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView;
Firebase rootRef =  new Firebase("https://fir-3-e5ce7.firebaseio.com/condition");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firebasedata);

    rootRef.child("message").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
           String superr = (String) snapshot.getValue();
            textView.setText(superr);

        }

        @Override public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) { }
    });
}
```

JSON file is also downloaded and placed in src folder. Internet permission is added also.

Google services and Repository is Version 31. Android Studio 2.1

So what is the problem?

Comment: What error do you get? What does the stack trace in logcat say?

Comment: Please add your stack trace to your question, there will be much more error detail than `unfortunately stopped`.

Comment: Also try to check logs.

Comment: ok .. Stack trace said that the error is in the line that contains the url :                                                                                                  Firebase rootRef =  new Firebase("https://fir-3-e5ce7.firebaseio.com/condition");

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: You need to set the Android context using Firebase.setAndroidContext() before using Firebase.
```

Move the initialization of `rootRef` to after the statement that sets the Firebase Android context:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    Firebase rootRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        rootRef =  new Firebase("https://fir-3-e5ce7.firebaseio.com/condition");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct answer....

Just :  Download the latest version of android studio 2.1.2 and update all plugins and repositories....

Thanks ALL !